# How to size <div> to fit the image inside?

Tags: html, css, resize

I have such a div:

```
<div class="game_img_div">
<a href="./play.php?game=free-kick-fusion">
<img class="gamethumb" src= " ./images/thumbs/free-kick-fusion.jpg">
</img>
</a>
</div><!--game_img_div-->
```

and the .CSS only contains

```
img.gamethumb
{
height:6em;
}
```

So the picture resizes according to its aspect ratio, say it has dimensions (6em,Yem).
I want the ".game_img_div" to also have the dimensions (6em,Yem).

How can I do it? Thanks !

Comment: Maybe float it? `div.game_img_div { float:left; }`

Answer (score 2):

```css
img.gamethumb {
    height:6em;
}
div.game_img_div {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: If you float it, you may wish to do `clear: both;` afterwards to place the rest of the elements on a new line.

Comment: @marvin Floating an element has other side effects, such as changing how the surrounding elements flow around it.  That may not be what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

Change the display type of the container div:

```
.game_img_div {
    display: inline-block; /* `display: table` also works */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8GK4/

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
.game_img_div { float:left; }
img.gamethumb { float:left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95ZUw/

Answer (score 0):

try for css:

```
div.game_img_div {width:auto; display:block; position:relative}
img.gamethumb {height: 6em; max-width:100%;}
```

and the img tag it's without `</ img>`