# How to arrange a <div> under two others?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm trying to implement a `<div>` which has 3 sub `<div>`'s (see the image)
[image]

div1 has an image inside it, and it's height is fixed with .css like

```
.image_inside_div1
{
height:6em;
}

.div1
{
float:left; /* so it fits to the image */
}

.div2
{
width:50%; /* not a great solution. How do I fill the rest (remaining from div1) of outerdiv's width? */
}

.div3
{
/*This is my primary question. How do implement div3 ?*/
width:100%;
position: ???
bottom: 0 ???
height: ???
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Finish the first question before asking another: [How to size <div> to fit the image inside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895698/how-to-size-div-to-fit-the-image-inside/14895841#14895841)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/k5nqm/ -- solution is incomplete; it requires the `6em` height on `.div2` as well, but maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
.div3
{
/*This is my primary question. How do implement div3 ?*/
width:100%;
float: left;
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both, div1 and div2 with another div. That is it.

```
<div>
    <div>
         <div id="div1"></div>
         <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C6Q46/ . Important bits

```
.outer:after { content: " "; display: block; overflow: hidden; clear: both; height: 0; }
.div2 { overflow: hidden; }
.div3 { width: 100%; clear; both; }
```